# SQL Query with group and having

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I'm trying to select all client ID's that has `TypeId` equal 1 but not `TypeId` equal 3.

Table example:

```
---------------------
| ClientID | TypeId |
---------------------
|     1    |    1   |
|     1    |    3   |
|     2    |    3   |
|     3    |    1   |
---------------------
```

My query:

```
SELECT ClientId, TypeId
FROM Table
GROUP BY ClientId, TypeId
HAVING TypeId != 3
```

What I have:

```
---------------------
| ClientID | TypeId |
---------------------
|     1    |    1   |
|     3    |    1   |
---------------------
```

What I expect:

```
---------------------
| ClientID | TypeId |
---------------------
|     3    |    1   |
---------------------
```

The critical thing is that the table have more than 3 * 10^8 registers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JohnBustos Nope, because I don't want to find the TypeId but the ClientId that doesn't have TypeId equal 3. This way the query will discard all typeId 3 but not the clients that have this type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest aggregation and `having`:

```
SELECT ClientId
FROM Table
GROUP BY ClientId
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Each condition in the `HAVING` clause counts the number of rows having a particular `TypeId` value.  The `> 0` means there is at least one.  The `= 0` means there are none.

If you actually want to get the original *rows* that match -- so all `TypeId`s associated with a client.  You can use a `JOIN` or window functions:

```
SELECT ClientId, TypeId
FROM (SELECT ClientId, TypeId,
             SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientId) as TypeId_1,
             SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientId) as TypeId_3
      FROM Table
     ) t
WHERE TypeId_1 > 0 AND TypeId_3 = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM Table AS t1
WHERE TypeId = 1 AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Table AS t2
                  WHERE t1.ClientId = t2.ClientId AND t2.TypeId = 3)
```

Comment: Is that a valid syntax in `SQL SERVER`

Comment: Now this may not work in `Sql Server 2008`  or lesser version's ;)

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: @ThiagoAugustusOliveira I have misread your requirement. Please check the edit I made.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos this apparently works too, I have to check the performance right now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT ClientId, TypeId
FROM Table
WHERE ClientId not in (select ClientId from Table where TypeId = 3)
GROUP BY ClientId, TypeId
```

Comment: You understand that the HAVING clause is unnecessary since you already filtered them?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your answer but I'll check the results and the performance before choose one answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could also achieve this with a common table expression:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ClientId
    FROM [Table]
    WHERE TypeId = 1
)
SELECT DISTINCT ClientId
FROM [Table]
WHERE ClientId IN
(
    SELECT ClientId
    FROM cte
)
AND TypeId != 3
```

Alternatively, try this:

```
 WITH cte AS (
        SELECT ClientId
        FROM [Table]
        WHERE TypeId = 1
 )
 SELECT ClientId
 FROM cte

 EXCEPT

 SELECT CLientId
 FROM [Table]
 WHERE TypeId = 3
```

Comment: Sorry, this answer still returning Client Id's that have type 3

Comment: That is odd, I am not experiencing that behaviour...but I will edit my answer so that it returns a distinct list of client ids rather than repeating them...

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong too, but all I do is to use all returned ClientId in my query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ClientID IN (#result)` @neil-hibbert

Comment: Unless I misunderstood and you want a list of client ids that have a typeId of 1 but also shouldn't have a typeId of 3 in that case I will add a separate answer with a different query...

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Have type 1 but not type 3. Your answer return the result very fast but isn't what I need :/